# How do I fix NTFS from Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, format, drive

Problem statement: I have an external USB drive that won't mount.

Context:

1. I neither have nor desire access to MS Windows.
2. See 1.
3. External USB drive is NTFS formated.
4. There is no RAID.
5. I've been a Linux user for many years and am not afraid of the CLI.
6. I would rather not wipe it and start from scratch but it isn't critical if I can't avoid it.

Error looks like:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/dude/External HD: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/dude/External HD"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Comment: Similar to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/727218/cannot-mount-usb-stick-errors-out-with-mftmirr-does-not-match-mft

Comment: I had the same issue. Tried several codes, but one solution that I tried is by installing and running boot-repair https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ Then create a new folder in your driver to test,... In my case it worked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can *try* to use `ntfsfix` in order to repair the NTFS volume.  This is a 'solution' in that it can fix simple errors such as the MFT and MFTMirror not matching up, and some minor filesystem incongruities.  Note that if `nftsfix` doesn't fix the drive up so it's usable, you'll need to use the tried-and-true "Use a Windows system to repair NTFS" solution.

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY`  (where X and Y are the letter of the drive's device and Y is the partition number, you can get this data off of `sudo fdisk -l` but it looks to me like this should be `/dev/sdc1` for your specific case) should then work.

Note that the still tried-and-true "complete" solution for fixing NTFS problems is a Windows system or a Windows boot disk (or even a Windows VM that you pass the external USB drive through to), and using `chkdisk` from the Windows system.

Comment: The only reason I bother with NTFS is so that it *can* be read from Windows but I actually can't stand Windows. ;-)

Comment: @user447607 Well, if `nftsfix` doesn't fix the problem, since you'll need a Windows system somewhere (VM or a boot disk to boot to temporarily) to fix the NTFS if `ntfsfix` doesnt work.  (ANd if WIndows `chkdisk` also fails to fix it, we can start to assume something is bad with the drive)

Comment: Not irrelevant, just means I DO have to wipe it. Anyway ntfsfix seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @user447607 Glad to hear it!  Please feel free to upvote my answer, and mark it as accepted with the checkmark at the left underneath the up/down vote buttons :)

Comment: I use Windows when I'm required to by other people but considering the historical business practices of that particular company, I consider it an ethical compromise and prefer not to contribute to it or it's ecosystem when ever possible. Especially when it's a personal endeavor, not a professional one. Also, if it's something we need to do, it should be doable on Linux as a general rule for our favorite OS. :-)

Comment: +1, especially for the last paragraph: `Note that the still tried-and-true "complete" solution for fixing NTFS problems is a Windows system ... and using chkdisk from the Windows system.`