# Unable to mount Elements(external HD)

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have inserted my MD Elements Hard Drive.I can not mount it,this is the first time that I have a problem like this.

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/milenko/Elements: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/milenko/Elements"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0)
```

I am confused with this.What does MFTMirr stand for?
How to solve this?

Comment: ($)MFT = manifest table; part of the directory structure used by NTFS. The mirror (which should be identical) to the main table differs, meaning their are logical errors on the drive.   If you write most data on this drive in windoze, i would use windoze to correct it. Yes Ubuntu has tools for it, but given its a NTFS implies to me you use it more with windoze...

Comment: @guiverc No,I have not used Windows for 5-6 months.It surprised me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/727220/3739) appears to answer your question. In general it's best to use Windows to fix errors on NTFS hard drives.

> But because it is NTFS, the only way to truly repair NTFS is Windows' chkdsk utility. (There is a ntfsfix command, but it is NOT going to be of the same quality of fix as Windows' utilities to check NTFS disks).

My personal experience aligns with this.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.